# Quelle est la différence entre « vers » et « envers »

Tags: vocabulaire, choix-de-mot, synonymes

J'ai l'impression qu'il y a une différence subtile entres les deux, mais je n'arrive pas à mettre le doigt sur ce que c'est. Quelques heuristiques serait utile, ainsi que quelqes exemples où un est plus convenable que l'autre. Ceci dit, il est possible que je me trompe et ils sont donc interchangeables.

Comment: Je pense que *envers* est utilisé principalement pour des personnes (à qui on s'addresse), alors que *vers* signifie le plus souvent la position en espace. Aussi, *envers* a une autre sense ("l'autre côté").

Comment: @RogerVadim *Vers* aussi a **un** autre **sens**, et même deux.

Comment: @jlliagre Tu as raison. Ca m'a paru que les deux sens de "*envers*" sont plus facile à confondre, car il s'git des indications de direction/position... mais c'est très subjectif.

Comment: Oui, le contexte permet de distinguer les cinq ou six mots prononcés /vεʁ/ en français. Ils n'ont pas de liens autres que phonétiques. *Envers* préposition et *envers* nom commun sont eux bien sûr liés. D'ailleurs, *l'envers* peut parfois se dire aussi *le verso* (et *l'endroit* *le recto*).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Il y a plus qu'une différence subtile entre ces deux prépositions. Elles ne sont jamais interchangeables.

[Vers](https://www.cnrtl.fr/definition/vers/2) indique principalement une direction, parfois une approximation.

> ***Vers** huit heures, il est parti **vers** le sud.* (**Autour de** huit heures, il est parti **en direction d**u sud.)

[Envers](https://www.cnrtl.fr/definition/envers) est plus rare, de registre soutenu, et implique qu'il y a deux parties en présence. On peut souvent le remplacer par *vis-à-vis*.

> *Il éprouve une certaine animosité **envers** son frère* (*Il éprouve une certaine animosité **vis à vis de** son frère*)

Comment: Utile et clair comme d'habitude - merci !